# In plain Javascript, trying to filter for multiple values in an array that contains User objects that contain other objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, javascript-objects

thanks for taking a look at this. Sorry for length, trying to be clear!

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO:** 
I have an array of users (each user an object) and am trying to filter the users on multiple criteria ("males from France" OR "females from Spain and United States with Engineering skills" etc) but it's proven beyond my skills so far.

The hard part has been that the users are objects within a User array, but within each user object, some values are additional objects or arrays. Here's what the user data array looks like (abbreviated):

```
let users = [
{ 
gender: 'male', 
location: {street: 'Clement Street', country: 'United States'},
skills: ['engineering', 'underwater'], 
}, ...
```

Notice gender is just a normal property/value but country is within a location object and skills are within an array.

I already have a search button interface that creates toggle buttons to search on each criteria available, and every time you click a button, I add or remove that criteria in a filter object. The filter object looks like this, and uses arrays inside it so that I can define multiple criteria at once, like multiple countries to search, multiple skills, etc.:

```
    filter: {
        gender: ['female'],
    location: {
    country: ['Spain'],},
    skills: ['optics', ]
    },
```

**WHERE I REALLY GET STUCK**
I've created a filterData method that can successfully filter based on Gender (male or female) but can't get it to ALSO filter on country (within the location object) or skills (within the skills array). My current filterData method only goes through one iteration per user, but I've tried For loops and forEach to try to go through each of the filter's criteria ('Spain', 'Optics'), but it just doesn't work. I only get gender.

I think I have two problems: 1) somehow conveying in the code that the item 'key' in some cases will not be a value, but an object or array that must also be searched within, and 2) creating some kind of looping behavior that will go through each of the filter criteria, instead of stopping after the first one (gender).

That's apparently over my head right now, so any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated, thanks very much! And here's all the code I've been working with, including my filterData method.

```js
var filtering = {
  filter: {
    gender: ["female"],
    location: {
      country: ["Spain"],
    },
    skills: ["optics"],
  },

  users: [
    {
      gender: "male",
      name: "John",
      location: { street: "Clement Street", country: "United States" },
      skills: ["engineering", "underwater"],
    },

    {
      gender: "female",
      name: "Mary",
      location: { street: "5th Avenue", country: "Spain" },
      skills: ["confidence", "optics"],
    },

    {
      gender: "male",
      name: "David",
      location: { street: "Vermont Ave", country: "France" },
      skills: ["cards", "metalurgy", "confidence"],
    },

    {
      gender: "female",
      name: "Rachel",
      location: { street: "Vermont Ave", country: "France" },
      skills: ["disguise", "electrical"],
    },

    {
      gender: "female",
      name: "Muriel",
      location: { street: "Vermont Ave", country: "Germany" },
      skills: ["flight", "surveillance"],
    },
  ],

  filterData: (filter) => {
    const filteredData = filtering.users.filter((item) => {
      for (let key in filter) {
        if (!filter[key].includes(item[key])) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    });
    console.log(filteredData);
  },
};

filtering.filterData(filtering.filter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nifty trick called recursion, which is a function calling itself.

The updated code are: `checkUser`and 
 `filterData`

```js
var filtering = {
  filter: {
    gender: ["female"],
    location: {
      country: ["Spain"],
    },
    skills: ["optics"],
  },

  users: [
    {
      gender: "male",
      name: "John",
      location: { street: "Clement Street", country: "United States" },
      skills: ["engineering", "underwater"],
    },

    {
      gender: "female",
      name: "Mary",
      location: { street: "5th Avenue", country: "Spain" },
      skills: ["confidence", "optics"],
    },

    {
      gender: "male",
      name: "David",
      location: { street: "Vermont Ave", country: "France" },
      skills: ["cards", "metalurgy", "confidence"],
    },

    {
      gender: "female",
      name: "Rachel",
      location: { street: "Vermont Ave", country: "France" },
      skills: ["disguise", "electrical"],
    },

    {
      gender: "female",
      name: "Muriel",
      location: { street: "Vermont Ave", country: "Germany" },
      skills: ["flight", "surveillance"],
    },
  ],
  
  checkUser (filter, to_check) {
    if (Array.isArray(filter))
    {
      return Array.isArray(to_check)
        ? filter.some(val => to_check.includes(val)) // if what we're checking is an array
        : filter.includes(to_check); // otherwise it's a singular value
    }
    else
    {
      const all_checks = []; // this is to save every return value from the recursive function
      for (let key in filter) // going through each key in the filter
      {
        const checked = this.checkUser(filter[key], to_check[key]) // passing two values, which will be compared with each other
        all_checks.push(checked) // pushing the checked result
      }
      
      return all_checks.every(val => val) // checking that it passes the filter by ensuring every value is true
    }
  },

  filterData () {
    let filter = this.filter
    return this.users.filter(user => this.checkUser(filter, user))
  },
};

// filtering.filterData(filtering.filter);

// filtering.checkUser(filtering.filter, filtering.users[0])
const result = filtering.filterData()
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi A. Lau, 
Thanks so much for this. I’m going to go over this during next few days, with the debugger, and really try to understand each step. I’ve not had experience with recursion (and 3 months total coding “experience”), and am sure this will take me a while.

But just one question: right now, the filter object’s SKILLS array will only find people who have ALL skills listed in the array, not EITHER skill in the array.  So “Skills: ["engineering", "underwater”]” only finds users who have both “engineering” AND “underwater”. Any way to make filter find users who have either of them??

Comment: @k2director Yes, just change the `every` to a `some`. Code is updated. Remember to upvote/mark as answer the one that helped you most.

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked! I'm going to go through code this week and try to figure it out. ;-)

Comment: I've added a bit more commenting. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ A. Lau, thank you for these extra comments. They helped!  I *mostly* understand what you're doing in the checkUser function, but feel it will probably be a while before I could write such a thing. ;-) Thanks though. If you have a moment, one of the last things I'm unsure about is what you're doing with the question mark and the colon in these two lines:"? filter.some(val => to_check.includes(val))" & " : filter.includes(to_check);"?     I have looked through a bunch of documentation but can't find anything that explains what that ? and : mean. Thanks again...

Comment: `? :` are ternary operators. It's a short form for `if/else`. It's used in a lot of programming languages. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-ternary-operator

Answer (score 0):

Bit complex data structure, you should clean. However, solved what expected.

```js
const mergeFilter = (item, [key, value]) => {
  let val = Array.isArray(item[key]) ? item[key] : [item[key]];
  let m = value[0];
  if (typeof value === "object" && !Array.isArray(value)) {
    const k2 = Object.keys(value);
    val = item[key][k2];
    m = value[k2][0];
  }
  return val.includes(m);
};
const filterData = (users, filter) => {
  const filters = Object.entries(filter);
  const result = users.reduce((arr, item) => {
    let found = filters.every(mergeFilter.bind(null, item));
    if (found) arr.push(item);
    return arr;
  }, []);
  return result;
};

var filtering = {"filter":{"gender":["female"],"location":{"country":["Spain"]},"skills":["optics"]},"users":[{"gender":"male","name":"John","location":{"street":"Clement Street","country":"United States"},"skills":["engineering","underwater"]},{"gender":"female","name":"Mary","location":{"street":"5th Avenue","country":"Spain"},"skills":["confidence","optics"]},{"gender":"male","name":"David","location":{"street":"Vermont Ave","country":"France"},"skills":["cards","metalurgy","confidence"]},{"gender":"female","name":"Rachel","location":{"street":"Vermont Ave","country":"France"},"skills":["disguise","electrical"]},{"gender":"female","name":"Muriel","location":{"street":"Vermont Ave","country":"Germany"},"skills":["flight","surveillance"]}]}

const result = filterData(filtering.users, filtering.filter);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi xdeepakv, thanks much, it's greatly appreciated and I'll study over next few days. Quick question: any way so that the filter returns users that have ANY of the values in the “country” or “skills” arrays, instead of ALL values? Right now, the country or skills array will only return a user that meets the first value in the array -- ie, if the country array is [“Germany”, “France”], the search will return just the German user. Any way to make the search produce users who match any of the array values?
Thanks very much for your time. I’m looking forward to wrapping my heard around this!

Comment: instead of every, use some.. simple.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the one instance I found of "every" to "some" but search results still returned just the first string in the filter. For instance, if I'm searching for users in Germany and France, it would return the German user but not the French. I'll try to take a closer look a bit later, but thanks for your help!