# Javascript filter nested array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to filter this data:
[image]

I have 4 users in this example, all of them has key fbid there is stored facebookID if it matches given key user should be deleted from array.
So basicaly I dont want user int this array with given facebookid.

Any help would be perfect.
I tried deconstruct it like this :
[image]
But dont know how to filter it now

Tried this: `Object.entries(userMap).map(([key, value]) => Object.entries(value[1]).filter(value[1]['fbid'] == '315151515'))`

Comment: I answered something similar recently, see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61538865/in-plain-javascript-trying-to-filter-for-multiple-values-in-an-array-that-conta/61541605?noredirect=1#comment109210224_61541605

Comment: dont post images for data sets... can you post your data in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```js
var arr = [
  [{
    fbid: 111
  }],
  [{
    fbid: 222
  }],
  [{
    fbid: 333
  }]
]

const searchedFbid=222

const result = arr.filter(x => !x.some(({
  fbid
}) => fbid === searchedFbid))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yes, I will try your example at home, will inform if i succeeded.

Comment: @Emilis did that help in the end?

Comment: Hi did not had time i will inform, this is on my todo.

Comment: Works, like charm, where i could learn such decomposition, i read lots of mozila dev docs, but no luck?

Comment: How should the code change if seachedFbid would be an array or object of ids?